# Use a custom properties file

Tags: gradle, properties-file

I would like to have a properties file that deployed with my application so that I can access it at runtime. How can I have my `build.gradle` file access my property file located in `src/main/resources`?

I would like to use this file as I would normal use `gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want to read this properties file in your build.gradle file? You can simply:

```
def props = new Properties()
file("src/main/resources/my.properties").withInputStream { 
    stream -> props.load(stream) 
}
```

Comment: I would like to use this file as I would normal use gradle.properties.

Comment: You can iterate over the key/value pairs and add them as extra properties.

Comment: is there a way to pass another file as a parameter to gradle? Like gradle --properties-file=myfile.properties task

Answer (score 7):

Here's a method if you want to load properties from an external .properties file and merge them with those from gradle.properties:

```
def loadExtraProperties(String fileName) {
    def props = new Properties()
    props.load(new FileInputStream(fileName))

    props.each { key, val ->
        project.set(key, val)
    }
}
```

Comment: Better use `file().withInputStream()` so the stream gets properly closed even if the Gradle daemon is still running.